# Nav bar with different pages

Tags: html, css, navbar

I know that this question might sound stupid, but I'm a beginner so just hear me out. I have a nav bar with text but no links( About, Project, etc with no pages for the user to go to). How do I add the pages for the user to click on the nav bar and go to them( for example, when the user clicks on "About", he is transferred to the about page that I made). I'm using HTML5 and CSS3. Any help is appreciated!

Code for the list:

```
    <ul class = "list"> 

        <a href = ""><li>Welcome |</li></a>
        <a href = ""><li>About |</li></a>
        <a href = ""><li>Projects</li></a>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a folder. Open a text editor and paste the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="welcome.html">Welcome</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Save the file as "welcome.html" in the folder you just created.

Create another text document and past the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>About</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="welcome.html">Welcome</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h1>About</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Save that file as "about.html" in the same folder.

Open "welcome.html" in your browser and see if it works.

The attribute `href` is the path to the file where it is located on your computer.

Comment: @Banzay Nobody was a an expert in the beginning.

Comment: Sure, bro. With a smile business go faster.

Comment: THANK YOU GUYS YOU'RE LIFE SAVERS!!